# R: compute the bootstrap estimate using rms:bootcov on caret model and glm model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, statistics-bootstrap

How do I compute the bootstrap estimate for my regression coefficients using the function `bootcov` from the package `rms`? I tried the below with sample dataset but got an error:

```
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

library(caret)
trControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          repeats = 3,
                          classProbs = TRUE,
                          number = 10, 
                          savePredictions = TRUE,
                          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

caret_model <- train(diabetes~., 
                     data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, 
                     method="glm", 
                     trControl=trControl)

library(rms)
set.seed(1234)
reduced_model_bootcov <- bootcov(caret_model$finalModel, B=100)
```

The error is:

> Error in bootcov(caret_model$finalModel, B = 100) :    you did not
>   specify x=TRUE and y=TRUE in the fit

If I use the function `glm` to build the model, this is what I would do:

```
model <- glm(diabetes~., 
             data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, 
             family=binomial,
             x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
model_bootcov <- bootcov(model, B=100)
```

But again, I got a different error:

> Error in bootcov(model, B = 100) : fitter not valid

Comment: Hey, bootcov cannot take in glm objects, according to its vignette, it is used "for a set of regression coefficients from ols, lrm, cph, psm, Rq, and any other fit where x=TRUE, y=TRUE"

Comment: I guess you can use the package boot for calculating the bootstrap estimate for regression coefficients?

Comment: @StupidWolf. Thanks for your response. I am new to this technique. Could you post a working example on my dataset `PimaIndiansDiabetes`?

Comment: Sure no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a fitting function called Glm in rms, which is a wrapper around glm, but you can also use it if you are interested in using bootcov. So for bootcov to work:

```
library(mlbench)
library(rms)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

model <- rms::Glm(diabetes~., 
             data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, 
             family=binomial,
             x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
model_bootcov <- bootcov(model, B=1000)
```

To use boot:

```
library(boot)
glm.fun <- function(dat, inds){
  fit <- glm(diabetes~.,family=binomial,data=dat[inds,])
      coef(fit)
     }
model_boot <- boot(PimaIndiansDiabetes, glm.fun, R = 1000)
```

We can compare how the two different models bootstrap, of course the seeds are different and most likely you need to set the similar seeds first:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

melt_matrix = function(mat,NAMES,X){
colnames(mat) = NAMES
data.frame(mat) %>% 
tibble::rownames_to_column("B") %>% 
pivot_longer(-B) %>%
mutate(type=X)
}

VAR = names(coef(model))

plotdf = rbind(
melt_matrix(model_boot$t,VAR,"boot"),
melt_matrix(model_bootcov$boot.Coef,VAR,"bootcov")
)

ggplot(plotdf,aes(x=type,y=value))+ geom_violin() + facet_wrap(~name,scale="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: is there away to do it with the model from `caret`? Because I want to take advantage of the `trainControl` when building with `caret` (In particular, I'd like a repeated K-fold cross validation, like in the first part of my question). Thank you

Comment: You use cross validation to get the parameters for fitting. In the end the data is fitted over the whole dataset, see length(caret_model$finalModel$y) for your example

Comment: The result is the same as just fitting a glm, because there is no hyper parameters to train for glm? I would suggest just using the glm fit.

Comment: I also want to plot the AUC that is contained in the `caret$pred`. I guess because I want to achieve many things with one method...

Comment: You can use the package ROCR once you have predictions and probabilities to plot AUC